# Is it possible to split my screen in half and mirror the image on a raspberry pi 5?

Tags: screen, pi-5, wayland

I'm trying to do homemade VR using a raspberry pi 5 and I was wondering if there's a way to split the screen in half and on each side mirror the same image.

So far I tried some [xrandr instructions](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/xrandr-split-display-virtual-screen) I found online but the raspberry pi 5 uses wayland so apparently `xrandr` doesn't work. Someone knows how can I achieve this?

Comment: You are better off researching this in a linux context, as Wayland has actually been in use for years -- eg., as the default on Fedora since late 2016.   Searching "raspberry pi 5 wayland" right now is unlikely to be very fruitful.  Also, this is something a *window manager* or *desktop environment* could pull off, which is independent of the compositor.  Finally, if you are really stuck, you can opt to use X instead of Wayland and that will probably continue for at least a few more years.